# How do I write the following html code in codeigniter using HTML helper's functions?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

New to codeigniter. I am having trouble in writing the following HTML code using HTML helper's functions :

```
    <a href="" title="">
     <?=img( ["src"=>'images/LOGO.png', "height"=>"50", "width"=>'350',"style"=>"margin-left:-60px"]) ?>
<h5 style="position: absolute;color:black;top:40px;z-index: +99999;margin-left: 30px;font-weight: bold">Tours & Travels</h5> 
</a>
```

I tried it myself and wrote the following :

```
 <?= anchor("incredible_ukd" ,heading("Tour & Travels",5,"style= position: absolute;color:black;top:85px;z-index: +99999;margin-left: 30px;font-weight: bold"), img( ["src"=>'images/LOGO.png', "height"=>"50", "width"=>'350',"style"=>"margin-left:-60px"])  ) ; 

    ?>
```

But it is isn't working properly. Help please

Comment: is not working properly ? what is the problem exactly

Comment: It wasn't displaying anything. Your code given below works fine. Thanx

Comment: I would strongly suggest, where you can... writing good old HTML. Having php generate basic things just increases execution times... HTML does not get executed by the server so any way of using as much plain HTML in your views will pay you back as your codebase increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>">
    <?php echo img( ["src"=>'images/LOGO.png', "height"=>"50", "width"=>'350',"style"=>"margin-left:-60px"]); ?>
    <?php echo heading('Tours & Travels', 5, 'style="position: absolute;color:black;top:40px;z-index: +99999;margin-left: 30px;font-weight: bold"'); ?>
</a>
```